spring batch detached entity passed to persist issue
I'm encountering an issue with Hibernate where a detached entity passed to persist error occurs when using a @ManyToMany relationship in my Spring batch data migration project.
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST},fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "account_client",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")}
    )
    private Set<ClientProfileAcc> clientProfileAccs;

I'm using a customItemWriter with an EntityManager. When attempting to merge the entities, this error appears. Interestingly, the issue resolves if I only use CascadeType.MERGE only. However, even using CascadeType.ALL doesn't fix the problem.
Here are the details of my environment:

Spring Boot version: 3.2.4 Hibernate version: 6.4.4.Final Spring Batch
version: 5.1.1

I need to keep CascadeType.PERSIST as well as CascadeType.MERGE. What could be causing this issue, and are there any workarounds or solutions to fix it?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
does any one ran into this issue and i also want to use cascade.persist at the same time as well
but i have to use some other method to fix, if there any other ways to fix that would be a great help
